# Не правильно работает меню на C++

Tags: c++, меню

Меню работает как-то через раз. В начале оно работает точно, но вот после того как мы используем его, то оно начинает работать криво. 
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int v;
string IT;

void menu() {
    setlocale(0, "ru");
    cout << "####################\n# 1) Зашифровать   #\n# 2) Расшифровать  #\n# 3) Выход         #\n####################\n>";
    cin >> v;
}

int main() {
    menu();
    while ((v != 1) && (v != 2) && (v != 3)) {
        cout << "Ошибка! Введено неверное число!" << endl;
        menu();
    }
    while (v != 3) {
        if (v = 1) {
            cout << "Введите исходный текст, который надо зашифровать - " << endl;
            cin >> IT;
            cout << IT.length() << endl;
            menu();
        }
        if (v = 2) {
            cout << "Введите исходный текст, который надо расшифровать - " << endl;
            cin >> IT;
            cout << IT.length() << endl;
            menu();
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Вот скриншот проблемы:

[image: Сначала разные цифры работают нормально, потом все через раз.]

Comment: `if (v = 1)` - это не сравнение, а присваивание.

Comment: можете улучшить свой код, убрав лишные усовия и оставить только проверку на равенство с  3  while (v != 3)  выполнить код

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Спасибо, но я узнал способ другой и решил сделать меню с switch case

Comment: @ARHovsepyan У меня возникла проблема, если я ввожу строку с пробелом, то программа зацикливается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В C/C++ для сравнения используется оператор "==", в то время как "=" является оператором присваивания и, так как правая часть операции не 0, считает условие выполненным и выполняет код внутри